# UILabel and UIScrollView and CustomView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uilabel, custom-view

I have view. Make custom view and add on view.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.customView];
```

Then i added scrollView on customView:

```
[self.customView addSubview: self.scrollView];
```

Then i added some label on scrollView:

```
[self.scrollView addSubview: lbl];
[self.scrollView addSubview: lbl1];
[self.scrollView addSubview: lbl2];
```

And when i scroll i saw on my **VIEW** border of label. What to do with this?
Thx for help!

Comment: when you scroll you saw WHAT??

Comment: UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; label.text=@"aaa";
[self.scrollView addSubview: label]; and then when i scroll i saw some white line. i make in my suctom view corner radius. and in the corner i saw that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put a breakpoint in the scrollView's delegate method `-scrollViewDidScroll:` you can use the console command `po [self.view recursiveDescription]` to check what the frames of your views are and see if the problem is in the label frames or in other properties of your view's hierarchy.

p.s. the next time you ask a question spend a little bit of time improving it: it's not really understandable.